# Angular - Creating a model with Array property

Tags: angular, service, model

I'm trying to understand how to create a model that includes an array.
I am trying to do something like this but I'm getting an error :

**ERRROR**

```
Argument of type 'elset' is not assignable to parameter of type 'elset[]'.
```

**MODEL**

```
export class elset{
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public title: string
    ){}
}
export class pageModel{
    constructor(
        public type: string,
        public set: elset[]
    ){}
}
```

**SERVICE**

```
@Injectable()
export class customService {
    constructor ( ){}

    types = [
        new pageModel('home', 
                     new elset('something','somethingelse')
                     )
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined the second parameter as **an array of** `elset` instances here:

```
export class pageModel{
    constructor(
        public type: string,
        public set: elset[]  <--------------------
    ){}
}
```

So you need to pass an array:

```
new pageModel('home', [new elset('something','somethingelse')])
```

Comment: Yep, Thank you. @Maximus, if it is an object then it would be 

 public set: elset{} ? and then I could do 

new pageModel('home', new elset('something','somethingelse')

Comment: simply `public set: elset`, yes, then you'd be able to do the way you did it